# Using variable value in regex in R

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, gsub

How can I use a variable value and a regex position expression together in R? For example, in the following code, how would I replace only cases of "zzz" that come at the start or end of a string? This works for all values of "zzz"

```
target_nos <- c("1","2","zzz","4")
sample_text <- cbind("1 dog 1","3 cats zzz","zzz foo 1")
for (i in 1:length(target_nos))
{
sample_text <- gsub(pattern = target_nos[i],replacement = "REPLACED", x = 
sample_text)
}
```

But how would I include the ^ and $ position markers? This throws an error

```
sample_text <- gsub(pattern = ^target_nos[1],replacement = "REPLACED", x = 
sample_text)
```

This runs, but interprets the variable literally, rather than calling the value

```
sample_text <- gsub(pattern = "^target_nos[1]", replacement = "REPLACED", x = 
sample_text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `^` and `$` characters to be within the regex pattern strings.  In other words, `target_nos` could be this:

```
"^1"   "^2"   "^zzz" "^4"   "1$"   "2$"   "zzz$" "4$"
```

To build that programmatically from what you've got, you could do this:

```
target_nos <- c("1","2","zzz","4")
target_nos <- c(paste0('^', target_nos), paste0(target_nos, '$'))
```